# google font is not working, lato and raleway

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

I am trying to import font from google but its not working properly. 
In local system everything is fine but when we publish code and upload on server then it not working, using default browser font.

> Platform : MVC.net 4.5 | Bootstrap 3.3.4 | HTML5 | CSS3

here is css.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,800,700,900);

body {  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;}
.banner h1{font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
```

Comment: try with quotes @import url('');

Comment: Are the `@import` rules at the top you your stylesheet? Try importing the fonts in you `<head>`.

Comment: thanks but.. not working.

Comment: Are you using special Characters like latin or turkish in your content??Can we have a link of the website?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/l55uq7g

Answer (score 5):

Very probably it's because of mix between secured (https) and unsecured (http) protocols. Removing the 'http:' from the font address you let the browser to make choice. Try the following code:

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,800,700,900);
```

Comment: Have you tried to research the problem using browser development tools (network tab in case of IE)?

Answer (score 0):

Is it because of Non-English or special Characters?

Can you try Adding "&subset=latin,latin-ext".

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway&subset=latin,latin-ext);

    p{
      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
    h1{
      font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/Prashantsani/pen/qdZYRP 

Did you add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` ?